# .match() returns null if one group doesn't match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I gotta check several strings which contain a alphanumeric sub string, and might contain a list in brackets where the entries are separated by ":"

Example:

```
"this(is:an:example)"
"thisAsWell"
```

First of all, I search for alphasubstring and the list, then I break the list to an array.

```
.match(/([a-z]*)\((.*)\)/)
 .spit(":")
```

Works well for strings that contain both, alphanumeric and the list, but not if one is missing.

Examples:

```
// .match(...)
"abc"  
  -> [ "abc" , null , null ]
"abc(1,2,3)"
  -> [ "abc(1,2,3)" , "abc" , "1:2:3" ]
"(1:2:3)"
  -> [ "(1:2:3)" , null , null ]
```

How do I handle it the best, to check for both substrings *optionally*?
I'm thinking of a possible return like:

```
"abc"  
  -> [ "abc" , "abc" , null ]
"abc(1,2,3)"
  -> [ "abc(1,2,3)" , "abc" , "1:2:3" ]
"(1:2:3)"
  -> [ "(1:2:3)" , null , "1:2:3" ]
```

*Superawesome answer would split the list per regex, if possible.*

Comment: Use [`?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark): _“Matches the preceding character 0 or 1 time.”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both parts optional:

```
var re = /(?=.)([a-z]*)(?:\(([^)]*)\))?/
```

`(?=.)` is lookahead to make sure that we don't match empty input.

**Testing:**

```
abc".match(re)
["abc", "abc", undefined]

"abc(1,2,3)".match(re)
["abc(1,2,3)", "abc", "1,2,3"]

"(1,2,3)".match(re)
["(1,2,3)", "", "1,2,3"]

"".match(re)
null
```